# C# Equivalent for stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding?

Tags: c#, iphone, windows-phone

I'm trying to find a way to mimic the behavior of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` from the iPhone, using C# (for Windows Phone).

I don't know anything about iPhone programming, and a web search for that doesn't seem to provide any document pages that might explain what it actually does to help me figure out how to mimic it. I mean, I can see that it "percent escapes" a string using an encoding, but I can't find any examples of what it does to confirm that the output I would be getting is correct. Is it just a simple URL Encode?

Comment: Good Lord, who came up with those names, Mary Poppins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure if I understood your question, but [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) might be what you're looking for. At MSDN you'll find it's definition and examples.

Update: [this is the official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) from Apple, regarding the iOS method you mentioned.

Comment: Please summarize your link, so that there is some context in your answer.  Link only answers are subject to link rot, and a whole host of other ills.

Comment: My question is that I don't know what that iPhone function does (since I have not seen any examples of it's output), so I don't know what function in C# will replicate it.

Comment: 404, I've talked to a friend that is an iOS developer. He said that this method formats an string as a URL (that is, replaces empty spaces and special chars). If that's the case, the method I mentioned will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this  for urls

```
  var uri = new Uri (url);
    var nsurl = new NSUrl (uri.GetComponents (UriComponents.HttpRequestUrl, UriFormat.UriEscaped));
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (nsurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is very old, but for those still looking for an answer: `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` is the C# equivalent of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` in Objective C. This is what one should use while composing email etc. in mobile apps / iOS / iPhone app (Xamarin). The difference between `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` is -

> The UrlEncode method converts each space character to a plus character (+). The UrlPathEncode method converts each space character into the string "%20", which represents a space in hexadecimal notation. Use the UrlPathEncode method when you encode the path portion of a URL in order to guarantee a consistent decoded URL, regardless of which platform or browser performs the decoding.

Also, though the MSDN docs recommend to use **UrlEncode** instead of **UrlPathEncode**, only latter is what will work in the referenced scenario.

[Update] Doesn't work same in Android (Xamarin), if you have encoded strings, you'd need to decode them back using **HttpUtility.UrlDecode**.